# Cloudfoundry broken bosh_cli_plugin_micro?

Tags: cloud-foundry

trying to setup Cloudfoundry, following the documentation at :

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/vsphere/deploying_micro_bosh.html

moment I install bosh_cli_plugin_micro

```
gem install bosh_cli_plugin_micro
```

bosh breaks as follows :

```
root@cloud:~# bosh
Failed to load plugin /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bosh_cli_plugin_micro-1.2597.0/lib/bosh/cli/commands/micro.rb: cannot load such file -- cloud/provider
```

Anyone have any ideas on what might be wrong?

```
root@cloud:~# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the latest without issue, using this:

```
gem install -V bosh_cli bosh_cli_plugin_micro --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

The -V switch is for verbose output and should provide you with helpful context.

You can sanity check by running the following after install (may need to restart terminal window):

```
~ bosh -v                                           
BOSH 1.2981.0
```